# i cannot use let or for clauses in my query, it always says its a reserved keyword

Tags: couchbase, sql++

why i cannot use let or for clauses in my query, it always says its a reserved keyword, following is my query:

for "FOR" clause:

```
`SELECT properties.hotelId, MIN(ARRAY_AVG(rate.base_rate) FOR rate IN ARRAY_AGG(inventory.property_rates) END) AS min_avg_base_rate
FROM global properties
JOIN global inventory ON properties.hotelId = inventory.hotelId
WHERE inventory.date BETWEEN "2024-01-01" AND "2024-01-05"
GROUP BY properties.hotelId;`
```

for "LET" clause:

````
SELECT properties.hotelId, MIN(avg_base_rate) AS min_avg_base_rate
FROM global properties
JOIN global inventory ON properties.hotelId = inventory.hotelId
UNNEST inventory.property_rates AS rate
WHERE inventory.date BETWEEN "2024-01-01" AND "2024-01-05"
GROUP BY properties.hotelId
LET avg_rates = ARRAY_AGG(rate.base_rate) FOR rate IN inventory.property_rates END
SELECT properties.hotelId, MIN(ARRAY_AVG(rate) FOR rate IN avg_rates END) AS min_avg_base_rate;```
````

Comment: and the docs are always right (see: https://docs.couchbase.com/cloud/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/reservedwords.html#:~:text=FOLLOWING-,FOR,-FORCE), so what is your question ?

Comment: Can you link to the documentation where FOR is explained? Because it is not as standard SQL key word....

Comment: Or (try to) explain what you want to do, because currently ...... 

Comment: @Luuk thanks but i tried what the docs suggested , i.e. using escaped identifiers it still doesn't works every time it outputs an error "[
  {
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - line 7, column 1, at: LET (reserved word)"
  }
]"


the modified query is " LET `avg_rates` = ARRAY_AGG(`rate`.`base_rate`) FOR `rate` IN `inventory`.`property_rates` END "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT properties.hotelId, 
       MIN(ARRAY_AVG(ARRAY rate.base_rate FOR rate IN inventory.property_rates END)) AS min_avg_base_rate
FROM global AS properties
JOIN global AS inventory ON properties.hotelId = inventory.hotelId
WHERE inventory.date BETWEEN "2024-01-01" AND "2024-01-05"
GROUP BY properties.hotelId;
```

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html#range-xform